# Generic model that has many relationship depending on value of enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following class:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  enum platform: {
    wordpress: 'wordpress',
    drupal: 'drupal',
  }

  has_many :wordpress_posts
  has_many :drupal_posts
end
```

Besides `platform`, it also holds things like `url` and `category`. It also has a relationship of has many with `WordPressPost` and `DrupalPost`:

```
class WordPressPost < ApplicationRecord
  belong_to :blog
end
```

```
class DrupalPost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog
end
```

I would like to know, if it's possible to infere what `has_many` relationship should be the valid, depending on the `platform` value: if the `platform` value is `wordpress`, the blog should only contain relationships with wordpress post entities. I'm not sure if there is a Rails way to solve it. I would love if someone can help me and show me the proper Rails way of implement such data model.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of using a enum won't work here since assocations are class level and the value of the enum is only known on the instance level.

If you really wanted to use an enum you could hack something together with an instance method but it won't really behave like an assocation when it comes to stuff like eager loading:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def posts
    send("#{platform}_posts")
  end
end
```

What you can do is use [Single Table Inheritance](https://medium.com/@ghl234/single-table-inheritance-in-rails-6-emulating-oop-principles-in-relational-databases-be60c84e0126) to setup classes that share a table yet have different behavior.

First add a `type` column to the table:

```
class AddDetailsToBlogs < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    change_table :blogs do |t|
      t.remove :platform
      t.string :type, index: true, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

If you have existing data you should go through it and set the `type` column based on the value of `platform` before you drop `platform` and make `type` non-nullable.

Then setup the subclasses:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  # shared behavior
end
```

```
class WordPressBlog < Blog 
  has_many :posts, 
    class_name: 'WordPressPost',
    foreign_key: :blog_id,
    inverse_of: :blog              
end
```

```
class DrupalBlog < Blog 
  has_many :posts, 
    class_name: 'DrupalPost',
    foreign_key: :blog_id,
    inverse_of: :blog           
end
```

The main advantage of STI is that it lets you query as a single table and thus treat it as a homogenous collection, the drawbacks are that you are potentially wasting database space with columns containing largely nulls and it can become quite unweildy if the types differ to much from each other.

Comment: Can I do STI with the post, instead of blogs? The blogs will always have shared behaviour, unlike the posts (`WordPressPosts` and `DrupalPosts`) that have different properties, hooks and endpoints

Comment: What I think I'm going to do is: use STI to do exactly as you explained, but the has_many relationship will point to either `wordpress_posts` (for `WordPressBlog`) and `drupal_posts` (for `DrupalBlog`)

Comment: Yes you could do STI for the posts table. You can then do associations that filter the posts by specifying the class `has_many :drupal_posts, class_name: 'DrupalPost'`.